# How to access list element in FEEL list literal expression in DMN?

Tags: drools, kie, dmn, feel-language

I have the following list of the object:

```
"animals":[
{
  "family":"cat",
  "color":"grey"
},
{
  "family":"dog",
   "color":"white"
}
]
```

I want to access first `animal` object that is in `dog family and white color`. I am trying to achieve it by doing this:

```
animals[family = "dog" and color = "white"][0]
```

But it shows warning as follows:

```
FEEL WARN while evaluating literal expression 'animals[ family = .... [string clipped after 50 chars, total length is 82]': Index out of bound: list of 1 elements, index 0; will evaluate as FEEL null
```

What exactly is incorrect here? I feel I am doing wrong something semantically. I also referred FEEL's specification but am unable to figure out what's wrong. I also referred dmn decision modeling documentation for DMN from [Redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_decision_manager/7.3/html/designing_a_decision_service_using_dmn_models/dmn-con_dmn-models#dmn-data-types-ref_dmn-models) but still I am clueless. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FEEL, the list's elements index starts at 1.

So the expression you want *to access first animal object*, actually is:

```
animals[family = "dog" and color = "white"][1]
```

This is documented in the [DMN specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/1.3/PDF) at page 126:

> The first element of a list `L` can be accessed using `L[1]` and the last
> element can be accessed using `L[-1]`.

[image: DMN specification list index starts at 1]

To provide a more friendly reference, this is ***also*** documented in [Drools documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.41.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#dmn-data-types-ref_dmn-models)

> Elements in a list can be accessed by index, where the first element
> is 1. Negative indexes can access elements starting from the end of
> the list so that -1 is the last element.

[image: Drools documentation DMN FEEL list index starts at 1]

...and equivalently for the productized [Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_decision_manager/7.8/html/designing_a_decision_service_using_dmn_models/dmn-con_dmn-models#dmn-data-types-ref_dmn-models) version as well:

[image: Red Hat documentation DMN FEEL list index starts at 1]